# cloudflare - ssl error

Tags: api, ssl, cloudflare

I try to get Cloudflare work with my website.

I have my website running on port 80 and my api on port 8443.

My proxy doesn't have a ssl certificate, I rely only on the one on Cloudflare.

I have set ssl to flexible.

I can access my website, but when I make an API call to my api on port 8443, I have the following message : `CloudFlare is unable to establish an SSL connection to the origin server.`

Do I need to have a certificate on my proxy for the API ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using Cloudflare's Flexible SSL option whereby traffic is unencrypted to the origin web server (but encrypted from Cloudflare's Edge to the end-user).

[image: Cloudflare Flexible SSL]

This setting will only work for port 443->80, not for the other ports Cloudflare supports like 2053 (or 8443 in your case).

If you want to serve SSL traffic through a port other than 443, you will need to ensure your web server is configured to work with Cloudflare in either Full or Full (Strict) SSL mode.

For more info:

- [What do the SSL options mean?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-)